# Inspecting pcap file with Wireshark: [Packet size limited during capture]

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

I'm inspecting a pcap file with Wireshark and some of the entries have this written in their information field:

`10001 → 27017 Len=121[Packet size limited during capture]`

I read that this happens when you capture packets with tcpdump and tcpdump cuts off the packet at a specific length.

What does 10001 → 27017 mean?

In the information field it says Len=121, but in the Length field it says it is 163 Bytes long. What is the correct length?

Comment: *"What does 10001 → 27017 mean?"* - likely these are the port numbers.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you Steffen!

Answer (score 0):

**What does 10001 → 27017 mean?**

As @SteffenUllrich pointed out, these are the ports.

**In the information field it says Len=121, but in the Length field, it says it is 163 Bytes long. What is the correct length?**

I am not entirely sure, but I think the difference in the length could be because of the `[Packet size limited during capture]`.

> By default, Director has a packet size limit to capture data on the wire. Larger packets than the packet size limit will show "Packet size limited during capture" when reading the packet capture. Taking a capture on larger packet sizes increases the processing time of packets.
> (https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/165718/error-packet-size-limited-during-capture.html)

So, my speculation is that the packet is 163 bytes, but only 121 were captured.